# CSV file import to excel sheet from Web using VBA with exact data format

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried the below code to import csv file to an excel sheet (Courtesty:http://investexcel.net/download-finviz-data/) and it is working fine. After importing the data, data type was not proper. Please see the screenshot.

[image]

The zero prefix was removed 2nd column after importing into excel. **Is there any property like '.TextFileColumnDataTypes' for QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;"... ?**

```
Sub GetWebCsvData()

Dim str As String
 Dim myarray() As Variant
'Delete existing data
Sheets("Data").Activate 'Name of sheet the data will be downloaded into. Change as required.
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents


str = "http://somedomain.com/filename.csv"
QueryQuote:
            With Sheets("Data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & str, Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("a1"))
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .TablesOnlyFromHTML = false
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                .SaveData = True

            End With

Sheets("Data").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("a1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=True, OtherChar:=",", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)

Sheets("Data").Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 12
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked quite nicely:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim filePath As String: filePath = "C:\\file.csv"        
    Cells.Delete

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & filePath, _
                                                      Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "test"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False            
    End With        
End Sub
```

The correct property is `.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)`. The `2` in the array stands for Text:

[image]

- [Tribute to these guys](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/498231-csv-excel-losing-leading-zeros.html).
- [MSDN - QueryTable.TextFileColumnDataTypes Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytable-textfilecolumndatatypes-property-excel)

Comment: I have tried that in the beginning, but it didn't work for me. :(.. Thanks

Comment: @JzWorx - you are right, the correct property is `.TextFileColumnDataTypes`.

Comment: @Vityata..this works for the csv file available in the local drive. But my requirement is to import directly from web. 
QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;

Comment: @JzWorx - this is strange, the source should be not important for the leading zeroes.

Comment: ok. do you know any property like .TextFileColumnDataTypes for Connection:URL?
Also any idea about my new question below?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878801/sending-filtered-transactions-to-contacts-via-outlook-using-excel-vba